# mysql inner join with another type of join required

Tags: mysql

```
[TABLE1]

 +----------+-------------------+-------------+
 | USERNAME | POST              | FRUIT       |
 +----------+-------------------+-------------+
 | Bob      | 'Hi There'        | APPLE       |
 | Jack     | 'Hello'           | ORANGE      |
 | Bob      | 'Today is Monday' | APPLE       |    
 | Tony     | 'That is ok'      | PEAR        |
 +----------+-------------------+-------------+

 [TABLE2]

 +----------+-----------+
 | USERNAME | FOLLOWING |
 +----------+-----------+
 | Mike     | Jack      |
 | Jack     | Bob       |
 | Bob      | Jack      |
 | Jack     | Mike      |
 +----------+-----------+

 [TABLE3]

 +----------+----------- +
 | USERNAME | LIKESFRUIT |
 +----------+----------- +
 | Mike     | APPLE      |
 | Jack     | ORANGE     |
 | Bob      | BERRY      |
 | Jack     | PEAR       |
 +----------+------------+
```

I am using the below query. It shows all records from TABLE1 if jack is following the user in TABLE2 or jack in the username in TABLE 1.

```
 SELECT t1.* 
 FROM TABLE1 t1 
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
 ON t1.username = t2.following 
 AND (t2.username = 'jack' OR t1.username = 'jack');
```

Now i want to do that AND to show records from TABLE1 if jack LIKESFRUIT in TABLE3.

Comment: What do you mean by "*show records from TABLE1 if...*"?  Do you mean return all records from `TABLE1` if the condition is met?  Or something else?

Comment: did my solution worked for you?

Comment: EXPECTED RESULT..

     +----------+-------------------+-------------+
     | USERNAME | POST              | FRUIT       |
 +----------+-------------------+-------------+
 | Bob      | 'Hi There'        | APPLE       |
 | Jack     | 'Hello'           | ORANGE      |
 | Tony     | 'That is ok'      | PEAR        |
 +----------+-------------------+-------------+

Comment: I will clarify.. using all three tables above (1) Show all records from TABLE1 when table1.username = jack (2) AND Show all records from TABLE1 if Jack is following table1.username in table2 (3) AND show all records in table1 if Jack likesfruit in TABLE3

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT t1.* 
 FROM TABLE1 t1 
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
 ON t1.username = t2.following 
left join tablet3 t3 on t3.username = t1.username
 AND (t2.username = 'jack' OR t1.username = 'jack')
AND (t3.username = 'jack' and t3.LIKESFRUIT <> '' and t3.LIKESFRUIT is not null)
;
```

Although I am not sure what do you mean by "show records from TABLE1"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT t1.* 
 FROM TABLE1 t1 
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
 ON t1.username = t2.following 
 AND (t2.username = 'jack' OR t1.username = 'jack')
 and exists(select * from TABLE3 t3 where t3.username=t1.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    username, post, fruit
FROM
    TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN
    TABLE2 t2
ON
    t1.username = t2.username
AND t1.username = t2.follwing
INNER JOIN
    TABLE3 t3
ON
    t3.LIKESFRUIT = t1.fruit
WHERE
    t1.username = 'jack';
```